# how to storing lat/lon info that read from mobile gps into sqlite database?

Tags: android-sqlite, coordinates

i build app that read coordinates of current location (every 10-20 meters) when move mobile in streets and displays current lat/lon, now i would like to develop app that save (storing) these lat/lon into a sqlite database. Any help (guide) as starting point would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to design the database schema. Storing just lat/lon would probably be pretty useless. You say every 10-20 meters, so there is something else, perhaps the time that makes the lat/lon useful.

So assuming that time is the factor that in conjuntion with the lat/lon makes it useful. Then per row you would want to store the lat, lon and time.

So that would be 3 columns in your schema, as the rowid (a special column) is included in all tables (with some less frequently used exceptions). Then 4 columns (the rowid uniquely identifies a row).

So your schema could be :-

- a column for storing the rowid, but just in case the standard android BaseColumns will be used which equates to _ID, the value stored will be a unique integer (long) and it will be the PRIMARY KEY (which implies a unique column).
- a column for the lat double should suffice
- likewise for lon
- the date/time can be stored as a long

Th next stage is to do all the database handling stuff. This is greatly simplified by extending the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

So you can have a class that does this. That class MUST implement two overiding methods **onCreate** and **onUpgrade**.

- onCreate is invoked when the database is created and is where you create the table(s) and perhaps other components (i.e. setting up the schema)

  - ***Noting that this is once for the lifetime of the database***
- onUpgrade is for handling when the database version is changed and is beyond the scope of this answer. It will just do nothing.

You probably want to minimise the opening and closing of the database as both can be relatively resource hungry. So a singleton approach without any closing of the database is recommended.

You may wish to include the methods that access the database (the CRUD) in the class.

So putting all the above together you could have, for example the class **DBHelper** as :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_LATLON = "_latlon";
    public static final String COL_NAME_LATLON_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_NAME_LATLON_LAT = "_lat";
    public static final String COl_NAME_LATLON_LON = "_lon";
    public static final String COL_NAME_TIMESTAMP = "_timestamp";
    private static final String TABLE_LATLON_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_NAME_LATLON + "("
            + COL_NAME_LATLON_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
            + "," + COL_NAME_LATLON_LAT + " REAL "
            + "," + COl_NAME_LATLON_LON + " REAL "
            + "," + COL_NAME_TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER "
            + ")";

    /* protect the constructor from being used elsewhere, thus forcing use of the singleton */
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /* Use a singleton approach */
    private volatile static DBHelper INSTANCE=null;

    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE==null) {
            INSTANCE = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override /* REQUIRED - ****NOTE ONLY EVER RUNS ONCE FOR THE LIFETIME OF THE DATABASE**** */
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_LATLON_CRTSQL);
    }

    @Override /* REQUIRED (but doesn't have to do anything)*/
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    /* Full Insert method */
    public long insertLatLonRow(Long id,double lat, double lon,Long timestamp) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (id != null && id > -1) {
            cv.put(COL_NAME_LATLON_ID,id);
        }
        cv.put(COL_NAME_LATLON_LAT,lat);
        cv.put(COl_NAME_LATLON_LON,lon);
        if (timestamp == null) {
            timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        }
        cv.put(COL_NAME_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME_LATLON,null,cv);
    }
    /* Partial Insert method lat,lon and timestamp */
    public long insertLatLonRow(double lat, double lon, long timestamp) {
        return insertLatLonRow(null, lat,lon,timestamp);
    }
    /* Partial Insert method (calls full method) */
    public long insertLatLonRow(double lat, double lon) {
        return insertLatLonRow(null,lat,lon,null);
    }

    /* Extract data */
    public Cursor getLatLonsForAPeriod(long start_timestamp, long end_timestamp) {
        return db.query(
                TABLE_NAME_LATLON, /* The table that the rows will be SELECTed from */
                null /* ALL COLUMNS */,
                COL_NAME_TIMESTAMP + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", /* The WHERE clause (less the WHERE keyword) note that ?'s will be bound (replaced)*/
                new String[]{String.valueOf(start_timestamp),String.valueOf(end_timestamp)}, /* The values to be bound first replaces the first?, 2nd the 2nd .... */
                null, /* no GROUP BY clause*/
                null, /* no HAVING clause */
                COL_NAME_TIMESTAMP /* ORDER BY clause */
        );
    }
}
```

The DBHelper will do nothing on it's own so here's an example of utilising it. This will insert some data (2 rows) and then extract the data and write it to the log:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(this);

        /* Add some test data */
        mDBHelper.insertLatLonRow(10.1,100.5678);
        mDBHelper.insertLatLonRow(null,11.1,11.6789,(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - (60 * 60)); /* 1 hour before */

        /* Extract the data */
        Cursor csr = mDBHelper.getLatLonsForAPeriod((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - (10 * 60 * 60),System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + (60 * 60));
        int id_offset = csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_NAME_LATLON_ID);
        int lat_offset = csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_NAME_LATLON_LAT);
        int lon_offset = csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_NAME_LATLON_LON);
        int ts_offset = csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_NAME_TIMESTAMP);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "LATLONINFO",
                    "ID is " + csr.getString(id_offset)
                            + " LAT is " + csr.getDouble(lat_offset)
                            + " LON is " + csr.getDouble(lon_offset)
                            + " TimeStamp is " + csr.getLong(ts_offset)

            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** :-

When run 2 rows will be inserted the 2nd row have a time 1 hour before the first. Then the data is extracted (for rows between 10 hours ago and 1 hour in the future (all rows as both fir this criteria)). However, as they are ORDERED according to the timestamp (in ascending order (the default)) the 2nd row is shown first.

The log thus includes (as expected):-

```
D/LATLONINFO: ID is 2 LAT is 11.1 LON is 11.6789 TimeStamp is 1656841299
D/LATLONINFO: ID is 1 LAT is 10.1 LON is 100.5678 TimeStamp is 1656844899
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot, but i want know these codes can lat/lon that read from mobile storing into database?

Comment: hi, thanks, but your codes did not create any database, please check your codes